# Part order by in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
id |  datetime
```

How can I order by id, but bump up the most recent 2 dated rows to positions 1 and 5?

I cannot add a sort column.

Is this possible with sql or would I need to do some array sorting in php?

-------Edit

```
id | datetime
1    2000-01-01 00:00:00
2    2000-01-01 00:00:10
3    2000-01-01 00:00:02
4    2000-01-01 00:00:09
5    2000-01-01 00:00:20
6    2000-01-01 00:00:05
```

I would expect to get out the latest 2:

```
ids:  5,2
```

Then the rest would be ordered via id, so it should look something like:

```
ids: 5,2,1,3,4,6
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking for

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected result ?

Comment: I will update my question, one moment.

Comment: in your case I would suggest sort on php side. yes it is possible to create mysql query that will return the order you need, but it will not be very powerful from performance perspective.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case I would suggest sort on php side. yes it is possible to create mysql query that will return the order you need, but it will not be very powerful from performance perspective

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66062/1

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT IF(@idx IS NULL,@idx:=2,@idx:=1) idx, id
  FROM table1
  ORDER BY `datetime` DESC
  LIMIT 2
  ) t1
ON t.id = t1.id
ORDER BY t1.idx DESC, t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using the ranking mechanism

```
select
id,datetime from(
 select 
 t1.*,@rn:=@rn+1 as rn 
 from test t1,(select @rn:=0)x 
 order by datetime desc
)x
order by 
case when x.rn<=2 then 0 else 1 end,
case when x.rn<=2 then x.rn else id end
;
```

Here how it works

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | datetime            |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |
|    2 | 2000-01-01 00:00:10 |
|    3 | 2000-01-01 00:00:02 |
|    4 | 2000-01-01 00:00:09 |
|    5 | 2000-01-01 00:00:20 |
|    6 | 2000-01-01 00:00:05 |
+------+---------------------+
```

First we will give some ranking depending on the `datetime`

```
 select 
 t1.*,@rn:=@rn+1 as rn 
 from test t1,(select @rn:=0)x 
 order by datetime desc
```

You will have

```
+------+---------------------+------+
| id   | datetime            | rn   |
+------+---------------------+------+
|    5 | 2000-01-01 00:00:20 |    1 |
|    2 | 2000-01-01 00:00:10 |    2 |
|    4 | 2000-01-01 00:00:09 |    3 |
|    6 | 2000-01-01 00:00:05 |    4 |
|    3 | 2000-01-01 00:00:02 |    5 |
|    1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |    6 |
+------+---------------------+------+
```

Then using an outer select do the ordering and with the help of `case-when` determine sorting within sorting as in the first query.

```
+------+---------------------+
| id   | datetime            |
+------+---------------------+
|    5 | 2000-01-01 00:00:20 |
|    2 | 2000-01-01 00:00:10 |
|    1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |
|    3 | 2000-01-01 00:00:02 |
|    4 | 2000-01-01 00:00:09 |
|    6 | 2000-01-01 00:00:05 |
+------+---------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```